# Wifi does not work on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, dell, 13.04

I have a Dell Latitude E5510 I dual boot with Windows 7 and the wifi works good with Windows 7 but when I load in on Ubuntu it fails to make a connection I had to put a USB Wifi adapter in to get wifi. I would really like to know how to fix this so I don't have to use a USB Wifi stick.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

Upon running Additional Drivers, if you have broadcom STA driver activated, try removing it.  Restart and see if your wireless works.